# Unable to setup jhipster with Google App Engine

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to setup my project with `jhipster gae`

Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
Executing jhipster:gae
Options: from-cli: true
Welcome to Google App Engine Generator (Beta)
WARNING! This sub-generator is still in development, please report bugs on Github

Installing App Engine Java SDK
... Running: gcloud components install app-engine-java --quiet

All components are up to date.
? Google Cloud Project ID quinoa-219713
This project already has an App Engine location set, using location "europe-west3"
? Google App Engine Service Name quinoa
? Google App Engine Instance Class B8 - 4.8GHz, 1GB, Basic or Manual Scaling
? Basic or Manual Scaling manual
? How many instances to run ? 1
? Google Cloud SQL Instance Name coco
? Google Cloud SQL User Name root
? Google Cloud SQL Password [hidden]
? Google Cloud SQL Database Name coco

Creating New Cloud SQL Instance

... Running: gcloud sql instances create "coco" --region='europe-west3' --project=quinoa-219713
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) HTTPError 404: The Cloud SQL instance does not exist.
child_process.js:644
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: gcloud sql instances describe jhipster --format="value(connectionName)" --project="quinoa-219713"
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) HTTPError 404: The Cloud SQL instance does not exist.

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
at execSync (child_process.js:641:13)
at exec (/Users/cmk/workspace/quinoa/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/gae/index.js:568:52)
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:267:7)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

Any idea why I am doing wrong ?

Comment: same here. you slq instance have to be named 'jhipster' since it is hardcoded into this file https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/1e0faa826a79156a7aad6376a5028b140d4f9760/generators/gae/index.js#L569

Comment: ty @cyril_lakech  i've lost to much hours for this problem >.<

Comment: I fixed the bug, it will be corrected in next release